# Why does `gameObject.SetActive()` take so long for a hierarchy?

Tags: unity

Why does calling `gameObject.SetActive()`(in the Editor) take quite noticeable time (in my case about 8 secs) if a game object has some significant number of children, while changing the state of the same object using its checkbox in the Inspector panel looks instantaneous?

I always thought that the checkbox [image]

and the `SetActive` method do the same job for the object. Don't they?

Test code:

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class GameObjectState : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool active;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(active);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        active = gameObject.activeSelf;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen a call to SetActive take 8 seconds! Can you edit your question to walk us through the steps to build a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example? Starting from an empty project, what would we need to add to our scene to reproduce this problem? Once we can reproduce it, we can test potential solutions to be sure they will work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126658/discussion-between-dmgregory-and-sergey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) pointed in [the discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126658/discussion-between-dmgregory-and-sergey) my `GameObjectState` component was causing many warnings of this type:

> *SendMessage cannot be called during Awake, CheckConsistency, or OnValidate*

As a consequence, excessive logging led to the editor freezing when toggling the checkbox.

While the reason for this warning is not completely clear to me, it is obvious that it was caused by calling `gameObject.SetActive` from the `OnValidate` method.

A possible workaround  for safely calling `gameObject.SetActive` could be to use a custom editor:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(GameObjectState))]
public class GameObjectStateEditor : Editor
{
    private GameObjectState _target;
    private bool _wasActive;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _target = (GameObjectState)target;
        _wasActive = _target.active;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        if (_wasActive == _target.active)
            return;

        _target.gameObject.SetActive(_target.active);
        _wasActive = _target.active;
    }
}
```